# Partial matching between arrays and alignment

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am working with a single large excel spreadsheet (multi-million data point). In the first column, I have ~2500 six digit identification numbers. In the second, I have ~70000 11 digit identification numbers. Every 6 digit ID is contained within one of the 11 digit IDs (for example, 701190 in cell A79 would correlate to 4900701190X in cell B41520). What I would like to do is create a function (or VBA code) that identifies the partial match and highlights, colors, or realigns the second array so that matches are visible. I was using

```
=MATCH("*"&LEFT(A2,5)&"*",B2:B29,0)
```

Which gives me an output in column C that tells me the right cell to go to, but it is very time intensive to do that ~2500 times. Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
Column A   Column B 
152028     2810152006 
152032     4900152010    
152033     4900152028 
152006     380152013X 
152007     4900152033
152008     4900152007 
152010     4801152032 
152013     290152008X
```

If you look carefully, you'll see that all the IDs contained in A are found in the IDs in B, but not at any constant location and not in a pattern. The real data is far messier than this.

Do you have any recommendations for a way to easily identify which IDs in Column B represent the IDs from column A?

Comment: You really dont want to create a function for this if speed is a concern. Instead write a sub using Instr function to identify the matches: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function.  Read both sheets into an array for better performance.

Comment: Very possible using VBA but not really necessary - if you can make do with pulling the matching ID's into col C instead of the matching row then see answer below

Comment: Why are you picking only the first 5 chars from ColA?

Comment: Yeah, I think @TimWilliams is right. You should be getting from the `RIGHT(A2,5)`?

Comment: What if multiple column B's match up with a single column A?

Comment: @Tim that was an error in the Q. It is right in the workbook.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm using a mutually exclusive database. The program that determine the data in column B will never produce a duplicate, and the numbers in column A are from a reporting software that only gives the six digits that identify the person.

Comment: So does that means you will have about 67500 entries in column B that do not match with any in Column A?

Comment: Correct. Basically, I'm just trying to identify where the IDs from column A are sitting in column B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with simple VBA.  I'm not sure how long it will take on a database of the size you state, as it has to loop through each item in column B for each item in column A, or 2500 * 70000 operations.  On my mocked up sample, on my computer, it took just over three (3) minutes to complete the task.

It will put in column C the item from column A that is found within the item in Column B.

You can easily see the matches by Filtering on Col C to exclude the blanks.

As written, it is case insensitive

```
Option Explicit
Sub MatchWithin()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vMatch As Variant, vWithin As Variant, vResults As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim sKey As String

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet2")
With wsSrc
    vMatch = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value2
    vWithin = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value2
    ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vWithin, 1), 1 To 1)
    Set rRes = .Cells(1, 3).Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vWithin, 1))
End With

For I = 1 To UBound(vMatch, 1)
    sKey = vMatch(I, 1)
    For J = 1 To UBound(vWithin, 1)
        If InStr(1, vWithin(J, 1), sKey, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            vRes(J, 1) = sKey
            Exit For
        End If
    Next J
Next I

'write the results

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 255 'so numbers don't get displayed as "#####"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This did it for me. Once I had the list of full IDs, I was able to exclude the blanks to get my exact matches. All that to pull some pass percentages for specific populations!

Comment: @D.R.Maddock Glad to help.  It might run a bit faster, depending on your layout, by adding `Exit For` with in the `For J =  ...` loop.  See my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combo of INDIRECT and ADDRESS to use your existing MATCH row to pluck the full ID in to column C:

You've found the row already with

`=MATCH("*"&LEFT(A2,5)&"*",B2:B29,0)`

Now use it to get the full cell address with `ADDRESS` using 2 to specificy col B:

`=ADDRESS(MATCH("*"&LEFT(A2,5)&"*",B2:B29,0),2)`

Wrap it with INDIRECT to get the actual value contained in the cell:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("*"&LEFT(A2,5)&"*",B2:B29,0),2))`

Comment: I think `INDEX` is better in place of `INDIRECT`.

Comment: Could you provide an example in place of what I suggested?

Comment: `INDEX(B$2:B$29,MATCH("*"&LEFT($A2,5)&"*",B$2:B$29,0))` to return the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably overkill but if you need to get the partially matched 11 digit ID to a 6 digit ID, running a SQL query like below should give you the result you need in a breeze.

```
Sub Partial()

    Dim con As Object
    Dim rec As Object
    Dim sCon As String, dataSource As String, sql As String

    '/* path of the target workbook, take note of the semi-colon */
    dataSource = ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";"
    '/* this is simply the connection string found on the link below */
    sCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=" & dataSource & _
           "Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO"";"

    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con.Open sCon
    '/* Sheet1 is where your data is, change to suit */
    '/* F1 is for Field 1 corresponding to column A, F1 - columnB and so on */
    sql = "SELECT a.[F1], b.[F2] FROM [Sheet1$] a "
    sql = sql & "INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] b ON b.[F2] LIKE '%' & a.[F1] & '%';"

    Set rec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rec.Open sql, con, 3, 1

    If Not rec.BOF And Not rec.EOF Then
        '/* Sheet2 is where your data should go, change to suit */
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rec
    End If

    rec.Close: con.Close
    Set rec = Nothing: Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

So below data in Sheet1:

[image: Data in Sheet1]

will be copied in Sheet2 like this (realigns as you call it):

[image: Data in Sheet2]

What I used is and `.xlsb` file, you can change the [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/) if you are using `.xlsm` (or `.xls` for lower versions of Excel). You can also run this in a separate workbook and just change the `dataSource` to the path of your target workbook.

```
dataSoure = "C:\User\User.Name\MyExcel.xlsx"
```